# Updating a python dataframe with new data from another dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to update an existing data frame (df1) with data that is received from a different data frame (df2). Data frame df2 may have new column, new rows or new data. Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish.

df1

```
    var1   var2    var3
a      8      4      12
b     -1     -4      -3
c      9     12      11
d     12     15       7
e      1      3      12
f      2      4       6
```

df2 (note that this is almost like df1 except it does not have column var1, has a new column var4, has updated values for var3, var2 is the same and has a new row "month s3").

```
    var2    var3    var4
a      4      10      12 
b     -4       0       4
c     12      15       9
d     15      12       5
e      3      17       7
f      4      16       8
g      0       0       4
```

This should be the updated df

```
    var1   var2    var3    var4
a      8      4      10      12 
b     -1     -4       0       4
c      9     12      15       9
d     12     15      12       5
e      1      3      17       7
f      2      4      16       8
g      0      0       0       4
```

What's the best way to accomplish this task? (I am specifically stuck on adding any extra row that may be present in df2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both dataframes share the index, the easiest way to combine them is to perform an outer join:

```
df = df1.join(df2, how='outer', lsuffix='_l').fillna(0).astype(int)
```

`lsuffix` marks the duplicated columns in the left dataframe with the suffic `'_l'`. `fillna` fills the missing values in the left dataframe with zeros. Finally, remove the duplicated columns:

```
df = df.loc[:,~df.columns.str.endswith('_l')]
```

Comment: What if df2 does not contain a row that was in df1? For example, say that df2 is missing row e (3, 17, 7). The updated df should still have row e with values 1, 3, 12, 0 for var1, var2, var3 and var4 respectively.

Comment: @arqchicago It will have that row. That's what outer join is for.